# Java enums and arrays

Tags: java, c++, arrays, enums

I have some C++ code I am porting to Java.

My code looks something like this@

```
enum direction {UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT, NEUTRAL};
int LINK[5];
.....
//fill LINK array
.....
if (desired_direction == LEFT  ) || (LINK[LEFT]  > 0) return true;
if (desired_direction == RIGHT ) || (LINK[RIGHT] > 0) return true;
if (desired_direction == UP    ) || (LINK[UP]    > 0) return true;
if (desired_direction == DOWN  ) || (LINK[DOWN]  > 0) return true;
```

So I have an array filled with ints and I am using an enum for the index of the array.

What is the Java way of going about this?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing the `()` chars in your `if` statements even for C++.

Comment: yeah . I edited the code for clarity before I posted the question and forgot to re-add the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, nothing is different.

In fact the only things missing here are the parenthesis around the two conditions of each `if` statements.

Also, your call to the enum value will be `direction.whatever.ordinal()` instead of just `whatever`.

Comment: this is not right, you can not use an enum as a index on an int array

Comment: you would need to call Direction.Left.ordinal()

Comment: @NimChimpsky thanks. I forgot that enums aren't naturally ordinals.

Comment: Just to clarify, I have not tested it, but it seems that the code IS the same except "if (desired_direction == LEFT  ) || (LINK[LEFT]  > 0) return true;" becomes "if (desired_direction == direction.LEFT  ) || (LINK[direction.LEFT.ordinal()]  > 0) return true;" etc (and yes, there are missing parethensis around the if statements

Answer (score 2):

You could use an EnumSet instead of the integer array. Enums in Java do have an integer associated with each instance (obtained from the `ordinal()` method, which you could use to keep the above code as it is), and EnumSet is implemented using a long as a bitfield (well, that's RegularEnumSet, and there's an alternative implementation for enums with more than 64 members- choosing is encapsulated).

So sth like:

```
EnumSet<Direction> links = EnumSet.noneOf(Direction.class);
// populate links (links.add(Direction.UP) etc)
if (desired_direction == LEFT || links.contains(Direction.LEFT)) return true;
// etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over a direction[]:

```
direction[] enumVals = direction.values();
for(direction dir: enumVals) {
    if ((dir == direction.LEFT  ) || (LINK[dir.ordinal()]  > 0))
        return true;
}
```

`enumName.values()` returns an `enumName[]` that holds all the elements of the enum.

Note that you cannot use an enum-element directly as a number. You need to call (for example) `direction.LEFT.ordinal()` to get the 0-based ordinal of the element in the enum.

Comment: replace "direction.LEFT" by desired_direction if you want it to do the same as the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Your enum could like this:

```
public enum Direction {
    UP(0), DOWN(1), LEFT(2), RIGHT(3), NEUTRAL(4);
    private Integer index;

    Direction(Integer index){
        this.index = index;
    };

    public Integer getIndex(){
        return this.index;
    }
}
```

and then your if statements :

```
Direction desired_direction = Direction.LEFT;
int[] LINK = {2,0,0,0,0};
if (desired_direction == Direction.LEFT  || LINK[Direction.LEFT.getIndex()]  > 0){
 return true;
}
```

Or you could reference the [ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method rather than explicity creating an index Integer. Like so `LINK[Direction.LEFT.ordinal()]  > 0`

However maybe using a hashmap could be appropriate (althoguh the logic is not quite the same as your question :

```
Map<Direction, Integer> myLink = new HashMap<Direction, Integer>(5);
        myLink.put(Direction.LEFT, 2);
        myLink.put(Direction.RIGHT, 0);
        myLink.put(Direction.UP, 0);
        myLink.put(Direction.DOWN, 0);

        if(myLink.get(desired_direction) > 0) 
        {
            return true;
        }
```

But my favourite is putting all the logic on the enum itself and then passing the int array as a parameter :

```
public Boolean getAnalysis(int[] link){
  return link[this.getIndex()]  > 0 ? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE; 
}
```

I also like explicit setting an index property rather than rely on the ordinal, just in case someone alters the enum in the future
and your call would like this

```
Direction desired_direction = Direction.LEFT;
return desired_direction.getAnalysis(LINK);
```